# See from where an activity is being called in eclipse

Tags: android

I have a large number of activities each calling some of the other and I am getting really confused as to which activity is calling which other activity . Show call hierarchy in eclipse does not show me this. Is there any way I get to see from where a current activity is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what the current Activity Stack looks like using ADB.

In Linux, you can use:

`adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run`

This will give you a nicely formatted hierarchy of currently running Activities.

EDIT: I'm assuning you have ADB in your PATH. If not then you'll have to specify the full path to adb (which is located in the android sdk folder).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a completely work-free method, but you could do `intent.putExtra("source", TAG)` in all the places where you do `createActivity()` and then `Log.d(TAG, "Intent started from: " + getIntent().getStringExtra("source", "unknown"))` in all your `onCreate()`s.

Answer (score 0):

Or, on a Windows machine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb shell dumpsys activity | find /i "run"
```

Modify the path to `adb.exe`, if needed